# trouble installing AMD graphics drivers on Ubuntu20.04LTS

Tags: drivers, graphics, gpu

Good day everyone. I have an issue with my computer graphics drivers.
I would like to use opencl for developement purposes and such.
However, I have an old computer with a Richland [Radeon HD 8670D graphics unit and an A10-6800B APU.
I migrated from Windows to Ubuntu because of easier / more diverse software developement opportunities.
I did check online on AMD's official site, but it seems the latest linux distributions only use the AMDGPU unified driver, which doesn't support my old card.
Is there any way I can get drivers somewhere to enable opencl or should I downgrade my distribution instead. I'd rather not do the second option if I can help it.
Any help and feedback would be appreciated.
Thanks.
PS: I did also check on here for answers, but couldn't find anything that helped me thus far.

Comment: You're better off replacing the card. It's really not very powerful, especially for OpenCL work.